# Vertical gap in Outlook 2007/10/13 between tables

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am having an issue with a 2px vertical gap between two tables on the above mentioned Outlook versions. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ddy/) of what I mean. And here is how it looks in Outlook (with the white gap)...

[image]

I have implemented border-collpase on each table, but to no avail.

Code is...

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td valign="top">
            <table border="0" width="290" align="left" class="mobile-half" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="right" style="padding-bottom:15px;">
                    <img border="0" src="http://placekitten.com/290/230" width="290" alt="useful tools"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            <table class="mobile-moveover" bgcolor="#6598b3" border="0" width="280" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr class="mobile-hidden">
                    <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" align="left">
                    <img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/37056558-100b-46fa-ad85-a0f2747d23aa.jpg" width="280" height="37"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                          <td width="40" style="padding-bottom: 7px; padding-right: 15px;"><a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/7cbd90ea-1023-4ebc-a9d8-dda116fec42a.gif" width="25" style="display:block; height:auto;"></a></td>
                          <td width="240" align="left" style="padding-bottom: 6px; padding-right: 15px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#ffffff" class="black-link">Budget 
                              planner</a></font></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td width="40" style="padding-bottom: 7px; padding-right: 15px;"><a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/7cbd90ea-1023-4ebc-a9d8-dda116fec42a.gif" width="25" style="display:block; height:auto;"></a></td>
                            <td align="left" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 15px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                              <a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#ffffff" class="black-link">Mortgage calculator</a></font></td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40" style="padding-bottom: 7px; padding-right: 15px;"><a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/7cbd90ea-1023-4ebc-a9d8-dda116fec42a.gif" width="25" style="display:block; height:auto;"></a></td>
                            <td align="left" style="padding-bottom: 7px; padding-right: 15px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#ffffff" class="black-link">Cut-back calculator</a></font></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="40" style="padding-bottom: 6px; padding-right: 15px;"><a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/7cbd90ea-1023-4ebc-a9d8-dda116fec42a.gif" width="25" style="display:block; height:auto;"></a></td>
                            <td align="left" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 15px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                            <a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#ffffff" class="black-link">Savings calculator </a></font></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td width="40" style="padding-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 15px;"><a target="_blank" href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/7cbd90ea-1023-4ebc-a9d8-dda116fec42a.gif" width="25" style="display:block; height:auto;"></a></td>
                            <td align="left" style="padding-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 15px;"><font color="#FFFFFF">
                            <a target="_blank" href="#r" style="color:#ffffff" class="black-link">Loan calculator </a></font></td>
                        </tr>
                <tr class="mobile-hidden">
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                    <img border="0" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/d20c202a4cf992f952df09668/images/a2c0633b-af9b-4465-8f0a-ec872a2c5a39.jpg" width="280" height="37"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>            




            <br>
            <br></td>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your fiddle is just a cat, with no while spaces, then the menu

Comment: I think this space is only appearing in Outlook 2007-2013

Comment: @SamDenton i removed the original image for privacy reasons, hope that clarifies!

Comment: yea, that makes sence, only changing the image seems to fix the problem, that or it is a local issue